# Will this box hold a ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan, fans

This is a picture of the box and a ceiling of my bedroom. It looks to me like a ceiling fan box but I just wanted someone else to give their opinion.

Is this a ceiling fan box?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Move the bracket and some of the wires and read what's printed in the box. That should give you a clue.

Comment: Looks like the mounting bracket is just a TSGB16, and the box is probably just attached with a couple sheetmetal screws, so no, it wouldn't be approved for a fan.

Answer (score 1):

Looks more like an post construction box. Just a nailer strap to hold it in place...
A ceiling fan box will have a spreader bar being it usually hex shaped bar attached to the joists